turned up the driveway

Gregory Ramos hitched his school bag up on his shoulder and turned up
the driveway to his house. (source)

What does "turned up" mean?
Is "turned" a transitive verb or an intransitive verb?
Is "up" an adverb or a preposition?
I have consulted seven dictionaries, but I still don't know what the sentence means.
Thank you.

Preposition (although the parsing doesn't help you understand). It heads the PP "up the driveway"
"Up" is sometimes used in extended senses of "towards a more important location". It is sometimes used in expressions to "along" You can search for discussions of "walk up the street" (and how it can mean almost the same as "walk down the street").
Turned is intransitive.  "He turned" means he changed direction. It's not the phrasal verb "turn up"
The quote means nothing more than "He turned (from the street, and towards the house), and walked along the driveway, until he arrived at his house".

Or possibly, “He turned [from the street] and walked along the driveway [which led] towards his house” – i.e., [up the driveway] [to his house] versus [up [the driveway to his house]].

That is interesting. Thank you very much, @Janus Bahs Jacquet.

Thank you very much, @James K. English prepositions are surprisingly powerful! My Japanese mind couldn't infer the "walked along" meaning.

Maybe add explicitly that "up the driveway" usually means "away from the street, toward the house" versus "down the driveway," which usually means "away from the house, toward the street."

I didn't know that. Thank you very much, @shoover.
